# Python - Converting xml to csv using Python pandas

Tags: python, xml, pandas, export-to-csv

I am new in here and I have been trying to create a small python script to convert xml to csv. Based on my reading various post here in Stackoverflow I have managed to come up with a sample code that works just fine.. However the data I am trying to work with has multiple layers and thus I am unsure how to extract the data at the leaf level.

Given below is how the data looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Transmission>
    <TransmissionBody>
        <level1>
            <level2>
                <level3>
                    <level4>
                        <level5>
                            <level6>
                                <ColA>ABC</ColA>
                                <ColB>123</ColB>
                            </level6>
                        </level5>
                    </level4>
                </level3>
            </level2>
        </level1>
    </TransmissionBody>
</Transmission>
```

I am trying to use the below code to try converting the xml to csv

```
import pandas as pd
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('file.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
final = {}
for elem in root:
    if len(elem):
        for c in elem.getchildren():
            final[c.tag] = c.text
    else:
        final[elem.tag] = elem.text

df = pd.DataFrame([final])
df.to_csv('file.csv)
```

This code however just pulls level2 and not ColA from level6.

**Expected Output**:

```
Transmission,TransmissionBody,level1,level2,level3,level4,level5,level6,ColA,ColB
,,,,,,,,ABC,123
,,,,,,,,DEF,456
```

**Updated code**:

```
allFiles = glob.glob(folder)
for file in allFiles:
    xmllist = [file]
    for xmlfile in xmllist:
        tree = ET.parse(xmlfile)
        root = tree.getroot()

        def f(elem, result):
            result[elem.tag] = elem.text
            cs = elem.getchildren()
            for c in cs:
                result = f(c, result)
            return result

         d = f(root, {})
         df = pd.DataFrame(d, index=['values'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you need to traverse the XML tree, so you probably want to have a recursive function that does that. Something like the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('file.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

def f(elem, result):
    result[elem.tag] = elem.text
    cs = elem.getchildren()
    for c in cs:
        result = f(c, result)
    return result

d = f(root, {})
df = pd.DataFrame(d, index=['values']).T
df
```

Out:

```
    values
Transmission    \n
TransmissionBody    \n
level1  \n
level2  \n
level3  \n
level4  \n
level5  \n
level6  \n
ColA    ABC
ColB    123
```

**Update:**
Here's when we need to do it on multiple XML files. I've added another file similar to the original one with ColA, ColB rows replaced with

```
<ColA>DEF</ColA>
<ColB>456</ColD>
```

Here's the code:

```
def f(elem, result):
    result[elem.tag] = elem.text
    cs = elem.getchildren()
    for c in cs:
        result = f(c, result)
    return result

result = {}
for file in glob.glob('*.xml'):
    tree = ET.parse(file)
    root = tree.getroot()
    result = f(root, result)

df = pd.DataFrame(result, index=['values']).T
df
```

And the output:

```
                    0    1
Transmission       \n   \n
TransmissionBody   \n   \n
level1             \n   \n
level2             \n   \n
level3             \n   \n
level4             \n   \n
level5             \n   \n
level6             \n   \n
ColA              ABC  DEF
ColB              123  456
```

Comment: A doubt: Why are you transposing it? The requirement was to create a csv with headers on the top row, unlike headers on the first column, isn't?

Answer (score 2):

you have an indentation issue on

```
if len(elem):
```

I guess this should resolve it.

Comment: `if len(elem):` is on the baseline, what kind of indentation do you suggest on that line?

Comment: What makes you think the if () line is on the baseline? To me it looks to be part of the for elem in root: loop, so it should be indented.