# Adding multiple dictionaries into a single Dataframe pandas

Tags: pandas

I have a set of python dictionaries that I have obtained by means of a for loop. I am trying to have these added to Pandas Dataframe.

Output for a variable called `output`

```
{'name':'Kevin','age':21}
{'name':'Steve','age':31}
{'name':'Mark','age':11}
```

I am trying to append each of these dictionary into a single Dataframe. I tried to perform the below but it just added the first row.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(output)
```

Could anyone advice as to where am going wrong and have all the dictionaries added to the Dataframe.

**Update on the loop statement**

The below code helps to read xml and convert it to a dataframe. Right now I see I am able to loop in through multiple xml files and created dictionaries for each xml file. I am trying to see how could I add each of these dictionaries to a single Dataframe:

```
def f(elem, result):
    result[elem.tag] = elem.text
    cs = elem.getchildren()
    for c in cs:
        result = f(c, result)
    return result

    result = {}
    for file in allFiles:
        tree = ET.parse(file)
        root = tree.getroot()
        result = f(root, result)
        print(result)
```

Comment: what is the type of output? `print(type(output))`

Comment: @anky_91, Dataframe that stores these values from the dictionaries

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Append dictionary to pandas dataframe in a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43957347/append-dictionary-to-pandas-dataframe-in-a-loop)

Comment: @anky_91 its <class 'dict'>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can append each dictionary to list and last call `DataFrame` constructor:

```
out = []
for file in allFiles:
    tree = ET.parse(file)
    root = tree.getroot()
    result = f(root, result)
    out.append(result)
        
df = pd.DataFrame(out)
```

Comment: thanks for the help. I tried the first approach you mentioned above and see that I am able to only get the header column returned back to the Dataframe `df`

Comment: I have problem such that in future I would be running this across different files that would have different header columns so I am not able to define what the header columns would be each time.

Comment: @codinglearner - So in lopp is not possible create list of dictionaries?

Comment: have added the loop statement, I am trying to overcome. However I am unable to add it to a Dataframe. Hope this helps.

Comment: @codinglearner - it is better, also is possible add some data sample working with your code?

Comment: the initial post has a set of 3 dictionaries.. These are the output for the variable `result`

Comment: please let me know if you need any further inputs

Answer (score 1):

We can add these dicts to a list:

```
ds = []
for ...:      # your loop
    ds += [d] # where d is one of the dicts
```

When we have the list of dicts, we can simply use `pd.DataFrame` on that list:

```
ds = [
    {'name':'Kevin','age':21},
    {'name':'Steve','age':31},
    {'name':'Mark','age':11}
]
pd.DataFrame(ds)
```

Output:

```
    name  age
0  Kevin   21
1  Steve   31
2   Mark   11
```

**Update**:
And it's not a problem if different dicts have different keys, e.g.:

```
ds = [
    {'name':'Kevin','age':21},
    {'name':'Steve','age':31,'location': 'NY'},
    {'name':'Mark','age':11,'favorite_food': 'pizza'}
]
pd.DataFrame(ds)
```

Output:

```
   age favorite_food location   name
0   21           NaN      NaN  Kevin
1   31           NaN       NY  Steve
2   11         pizza      NaN   Mark
```

**Update 2:**
Building up on our previous discussion in [Python - Converting xml to csv using Python pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55018004/python-converting-xml-to-csv-using-python-pandas) we can do:

```
results = []
for file in glob.glob('*.xml'):
    tree = ET.parse(file)
    root = tree.getroot()
    result = f(root, {})
    result['filename'] = file # added filename to our results
    results += [result]

pd.DataFrame(results)
```

Comment: thanks for the help. I am continuing from the other ticket where you helped me build the xml to csv convertor. Since it was a new issue I raised a new ticket on this. I have multiple dictionaries from each of the xml file but now trying to add them to Dataframe

Comment: I tried to add all dicts to a list by doing the below
`ds = []
for i in result:
    ds += [i]
    print(ds)`

The above converts the dicts to a list but not dicts inside a list as shown below.

Sample output:

`['name':'Kevin','age':21]`
`['name':'Steve','age':31]`
`['name':'Mark','age':11]`

Comment: OK, so let me clarify it a bit, on each step we get a dict like {'name': 'Kevin', ...}, right?

Comment: OK, great, can you check the code from `Update 2` please?

Comment: Added filename to the results with `result['filename'] = file # added filename to our results`